# How can systemctl display username and log file path in systemctl status?

Tags: 18.04, systemd

When I run

```
systemctl status <service name>
```

how can I also see by what user it is running and the path of the log file?

Answer (score 0):

## How to find the UID, PID and Log Target of an service (unit)

You can print the UID (user identity), ExecPID and StandardOutput (log-target) by running this command

```
systemctl show -p ExecMainPID,UID,StandardOutput <Name-of-your-Service>
```

In this example these parameters are printed for the NetworkManager service:

```
$ systemctl show -p ExecMainPID,UID,StandardOutput NetworkManager
UID=[not set]
ExecMainPID=1122
StandardOutput=journal
```

`UID=[not set]` is equivalent to root.

The journal path by default is found for

- persistent storage: `/var/log/journal/<machine-id>/system.journal`
- volatile storage: `/run/systemd/journal/<machine-id>`.